# wsgi - processing unicode characters from post

Tags: python, post, unicode, wsgi

python 2.7

```
raw = '%C3%BE%C3%A6%C3%B0%C3%B6' #string from wsgi post_data
raw_uni = raw.replace('%', r'\x')
raw_uni # gives '\\xC3\\xBE\\xC3\\xA6\\xC3\\xB0\\xC3\\xB6'
print raw uni #gives '\xC3\xBE\xC3\xA6\xC3\xB0\xC3\xB6'
uni = unicode(raw_uni, 'utf-8')
uni #gives u'\\xC3\\xBE\\xC3\\xA6\\xC3\\xB0\\xC3\\xB6+\\xC3\\xA9g'
print uni #gives \xC3\xBE\xC3\xA6\xC3\xB0\xC3\xB6+\xC3\xA9g
```

However if I change raw_uni to be:

```
raw_uni = '\xC3\xBE\xC3\xA6\xC3\xB0\xC3\xB6'
```

and now do:

```
uni = unicode(raw_uni, 'utf-8')
uni #gives u'\xfe\xe6\xf0\xf6'
print uni #gives þæðö
```

which is what I want.

how do I get rid of this extra '\' in raw_uni or take advantage of the fact that it's only there in the repr version of the string? More to the point, why does unicode(raw_uni, 'utf-8') use the repr version of the string???

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `urllib.unquote`, not a manual replace:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> raw = '%C3%BE%C3%A6%C3%B0%C3%B6'
>>> urllib.unquote(raw)
'\xc3\xbe\xc3\xa6\xc3\xb0\xc3\xb6'
>>> unicode(urllib.unquote(raw), 'utf-8')
u'\xfe\xe6\xf0\xf6'
```

The underlying issue here is that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what hex escapes are.  The `repr` of a non-printable character can be expressed as a hex escape, which looks like a single backslash, followed by an 'x', followed by two hex characters.  This is also how you would type these characters into a string literal, but it is still only a single character.  Your `replace` line does not turn your original string into hex escapes, it just replaces each '%' with a literal backslash character followed by an 'x'.

Consider the following examples:

```
>>> len('\xC3')         # this is a hex escape, only one character
1
>>> len(r'\xC3')        # this is four characters, '\', 'x', 'C', '3'
4
>>> r'\xC3' == '\\xC3'  # raw strings escape backslashes
True
```

If for some reason you can't use `urllib.unquote`, the following should work:

```
raw_uni = re.sub('%(\w{2})', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), raw)
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I "should" be using unquote but, hypothetically, what if I don't want to?

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong, but here is what you shouldn't do: `eval('"%s"' % raw_uni)`.

Comment: @Bjorn - I edited my answer with a safer solution that uses `re` instead of `urllib.unquote`.